# RailsAdmin Carrierwave Multiple Upload undefined method `filename' for nil:NilClass

Tags: carrierwave, rails-admin

Following Carrierwave and RailsAdmin instructions I can preform multiple uploads in RailsAdmin with Carrierwave, using aws S3. When trying to delete one of the images I get:

`undefined method 'filename' for nil:NilClass`

The assets field is a json field, `assets:json`

This is in my model:

```
attr_accessor :delete_assets
  after_validation do
    uploaders = assets.delete_if do |uploader|
      if Array(delete_assets).include?(uploader.file.filename)
        uploader.remove!
        true
      end
    end
    write_attribute(:assets, uploaders.map { |uploader| uploader.file.filename })
  end
```

I tried `uploader.file.identifier` but read that when using fog aws S3 the `uploader.file.filename` should be used.

My resources so far:

RailsAdmin
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/README.md#multiple-file-uploads

Carrierwave:
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CarrierWave

Stackoverflow:
[Rails Admin - undefined method `' for using Carrierwave multiple upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416886/rails-admin-undefined-method-for-using-carrierwave-multiple-upload)

How do I delete a previously uploaded image from this json array? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is certain `uploader`s don't have a file attached. So your error is because you're calling `filename` on `nil` - aka `uploader.file` returns `nil`.

You'll likely want to handle this occurrence, something like the following:

```
  attr_accessor :delete_assets

  after_validation do
    uploaders = assets.delete_if do |uploader|
      next unless uploader.file # <-- skip deleting assets without a file

      if Array(delete_assets).include?(uploader.file.filename)
        uploader.remove!
        true
      end
    end
    write_attribute(:assets, uploaders.map { |uploader| uploader.file.filename })
  end
```

Or if you'd rather remove *all* assets missing a file:

```
  attr_accessor :delete_assets

  after_validation do
    uploaders = assets.delete_if do |uploader|
      next true unless uploader.file # <-- note 'true' added here

      if Array(delete_assets).include?(uploader.file.filename)
        uploader.remove!
        true
      end
    end
    write_attribute(:assets, uploaders.map { |uploader| uploader.file.filename })
  end
```

Otherwise, the route you'll need to go down will be validating the presence of a file on an uploader, which is likely a separate question.

Hope this helps - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions here :)

Comment: The second piece worked. Removing all assets missing a file worked! Thank You!